# Controlling eigenvalues of a 4th order system

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations, control-theory

Consider the state space system $\dot{z} = Az + Bu$ with $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. We need to design a control law $u=−Kz$ so that all eigenvalues of $A−BK$ have a real part that is less than $−10$, where $K=\begin{bmatrix} k_{11} & k_{12} & k_{13}& k_{14} \\ k_{21} & k_{22} & k_{23}& k_{24}\end{bmatrix}$.

I am trying to look for a mathematical manual approach as opposed to one involving coding. I am not sure that such a method even exists without any assumptions. For me, I got stuck after computing $\det(\lambda I-(A-BK))=0$, which gives $\lambda(\lambda^2+k_{24}\lambda+k_{23})(k_{11}+k_{12}+\lambda)-(k_{14}\lambda+k_{13})(\lambda k_{22}+k_{21})=0$. This seems quite unapproachable to me from here and I think there should be a nicer approach to solving the problem, since the $A$ matrix has a rank of $2$ which I haven't used anywhere. Any leads and hints would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can set $k_{13}=k_{14}=k_{21}=k_{22}=0$ without losing generality, which means other parameters are enough to assign the eigenvalues anywhere you want. This is because this system can be separated to 2 identical systems.

Comment: @obareey can you tell me what it means for the system to be separated into 2 identical systems. How did you reach this conclusion?

Comment: If you write down the elements of $\dot{z}=Az+Bu$, then $z_1,z_2$ only depend on themselves and $u_1$, similarly $z_3,z_4$ only depend on themselves and $u_2$.

Comment: @obareey oh right, I got it. However, if you see my characteristic polynomial above, setting those 4 variables to 0 gives me an eigenvalue=0. The question asks for all the eigenvalues to be less than -10. Am I missing something?

Comment: A fast check with Mathematica shows that your characteristic polynomial is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$A-BK=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\-k_{11}&-k_{12}&-k_{13}&-k_{14}\\0&0&0&1\\-k_{21}&-k_{22}&-k_{23}&-k_{24}\end{pmatrix}$$ it is enough to take $k_{21}=k_{22}=0$; then the eigenvalues of $A-BK$ are those of the two sub-matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-k_{11}&-k_{12}\end{pmatrix},\qquad\qquad\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-k_{23}&-k_{24}\end{pmatrix}$$ on the diagonal. The requirement is then that the eigenvalues of each sub-matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-a&-b\end{pmatrix}$ (where $a$ represents $k_{11}$, $k_{23}$, and $b$ represents $k_{12}$, $k_{24}$) have real part less than $-10$. Looking at the trace and determinant, this is the case when $b>20$ and $a>100$.
Conclusion: A sufficient condition for all eigenvalues of $A-BK$ having real part less than $-10$ is $$k_{21}=k_{22}=0,\qquad k_{11}, k_{23}>100,\qquad k_{12},k_{24}>20$$

Comment: I think this answers my question, but I am not sure I understand it. a and b are submatrices, right? What does it mean for b>20 and a>100? It would be great if you could just explain it in a little bit more detail.

Comment: @unknown2718 Modified answer. Hope it's clearer now.